# Titanium Android file.read() returns null for external media from intent

Tags: file, android-intent, titanium, blob, external

When I invoke a gallery intent, I get the file ok, but trying to convert that file to a `blob` with `read()` gives null:

**Q) How can i get the blob of this file?**

Code:

```
    var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({ action : Ti.Android.ACTION_PICK, type : "image/*" });            
    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    win.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) { 
        if (e.error) { 
            alert(e.error);
        } 
        else {
            if (e.resultCode === Titanium.Android.RESULT_OK) {                  
                var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(e.intent.data);

                console.log('intentdata: ' + e.intent.data);
                console.log('file: ' + JSON.stringify(file));
                console.log('file read result: ' + JSON.stringify(file.read()));
            } 
        }
    });
```

Produces:

```
I/TiAPI   ( 2897):  intentdata: content://media/external/images/media/59
I/TiAPI   ( 2897):  file: {"readonly":true,"bubbleParent":true,"writable":false,"directoryListing":null,"symbolicLink":false,"h
idden":false,"nativePath":"content://media/external/images/media/59","executable":false,"size":0,"name":"butterfly2_large1.jpg"
,"parent":null}
I/TiAPI   ( 2897):  file read result: null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out that you need to copy the file to the applicationDataDirectory before trying to get it as a blob.

```
var intentFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(e.intent.data);          
var copiedFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, intentFile.name);                            
intentFile.copy(copiedFile.nativePath);                         
var blob = copiedFile.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Thank you, Thank you Dave, Have been on this for two days now and this saved my remaining hair.

I don't have enough points to leave a comment so answering again to put a few key points which perhaps may help others, as they seem not clearly documented.

The answer above solves a confusing error message when you try to read the file in downloads. The system seems to think it already is a blob, rather than a file handle, like this:

```
var pdf = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(intent.getData());
pdf = pdf.read();
if(pdf.exists()){
   //do something 
}
```

giving console message like

> Method is not supported org.appcelerator.titanium.io.TitaniumBlob : read
>
> Method is not supported org.appcelerator.titanium.io.TitaniumBlob : exists

Dave's advice also applies to opening a file (in my case a PDF) from Downloads or from mail using an intent.getData() that retuns a URI to these resources.

Additionally it may help to put:

```
Ti.Filesystem.requestStoragePermissions(callback);
```

somewhere early in your code if you want access to general file storage. Lacking this will cause constant permission denied errors.